# Excel-VBA: Userform window reposition with ScreenUpdating = False

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I've created a few userforms in a Excel workbook and whenever a user starts one I set `Application.ScreenUpdating` to false.

But when the user moves the userform around it always leaves a copy behind (see image)

[image]

How can I prevent this but still keep `Application.ScreenUpdating` set to false.

Comment: You can't - they're mutually exclusive. **Why** do you turn `Screenupdating` off as soon as you load the form?

Comment: For example: The user starts the function which fills the whole sheet with data (not the userform in the picture). I present them a progressbar for the whole process and disable the `ScreenUpdating`. The user moves around the progress bar for whatever reason and then sees multiple forms which doesn't look very pretty and maybe even confuses them to a point where they can't tell which one is the "active" userform. Another example: The user wants to add a new customer. For this, I make templates visible and select ranges etc. which I also wouldn't want them to see.

Comment: I guess you are doing most of the work through the clipboard, with select, activate, copy, paste... Is that why you are disabling screen updating? If so, you solution is to drop this non-recommended method (there is always a way to do without it) and you will not need to disable screen updating.

Comment: The reason I use templates is because each customer column is heavily formatted. It is much easier to just copy and paste the template column when a new customer is being added instead of creating the new column via code. If it really isn't possible to solve my issue, I'll just move the `ScreenUpdating = False` right before the whole process of adding a new customer begins and set it back to `True` after it finished.